# std::filesystem::copy throws filesystem_error

Tags: c++, exception, copy, filesystems, c++17

Attempting to run this code:

```
filesystem::copy_options copyOptions = filesystem::copy_options::skip_existing | filesystem::copy_options::recursive | filesystem::copy_options::directories_only;
filesystem::copy(pathA, pathB, copyOptions);
```

The first attempt is successful and operates exactly as I want and is expected...
The second attempt (after the pathB structure has been created) fails with this error:

```
filesystem error: cannot copy: File exists 
[C:\Users\Smith\Documents\Projects\ProjectA\bin\..\pathA] 
[C:\Users\Smith\Documents\Projects\ProjectA\bin\..\pathB]
```

The expectation I have is that using skip_existing or overwrite_existing should not throw this error.
How does one use this copy method without having to delete pathB each time before use?

[Link to cppreference i'm looking at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the flag `std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing`.

This solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I've tried this and get the same result. I also mentioned this towards the bottom of my question.

Comment: I implemented this in my machine and works as expected. May be something is wrong in your C++ installation.

Comment: Are you catching exceptions in any way in your implementation? I'm using a very basic config (g++ -std=c++17). Did you run the copy twice?

Comment: I used Visual Studio 2019 with -std=C++17.  I didn't use any special exception handling code and it was straight forward. Even, according to the documentation it should be correct.

Comment: which version of g++ are you using?

Comment: Any updates to this? I'm having the same exact issue, a crash with MSVC 2019 when using `std::filesystem::copy_options::updated_existing`. Oddly, `std::filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing` works fine.

Comment: This (the flag) did not work for me (still threw exceptions). One reddit post I found blames the GCC implementation being faulty. I instead worked around the issue by "re-implementing" overwriting a file. [ first calling "std::filesystem::remove_all(path)" and then "std::filesystem::copy(original, path)" ]

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue and turns out **it occurs when the two paths are completely identical**. In my case, the user set the output path, and then configuration files where copied from a source directory. If the user set the output path *as* the source directory, the command would end up being something like

`fs::copy("path/to/config.txt", "path/to/config.txt", fs::copy_options::update_existing);`

Which, even with `update_existing` or `overwrite_existing`, throws the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
  what():  filesystem error: cannot copy: File exist
```